# How do I change what appears in the "quick actions" menu on the contact record summary page?

Tags: actions

I know this is possible because I have done it many times before but now I can't find it! I have looked in the admin interface, the documentation, and on this here stack exchange. I am hoping someone can remind me.

I want to change the items that appear in the quick actions menu from the contact summary:
[image: screenshot of the CiviCRM quick actions menu from the contact record]

Where do I go to do this?

THANKS EVERYONE!

Comment: The only 'simple' way to adjust this is to add a new Activity Type afaik

Comment: I am totally misremembering, then. I thought this was something you could modify and new activities did not automatically get added to this menu. TY!

Comment: I'm with you Lisa. I am certain that there was a UI place where the actions could be enabled/disabled. I have two environments: the production shows Send an Email in the Summary Page Action dropdown; the development site does not show it. I am certain I changed this using the UI since I would not have made any css changes to effect the change.

Answer (score 4):

Just noting here that if you have access to your database and set the civicrm_option_value.filter_value = 1 for the activity type it doesn't show.

That wont be the same for all the actions, but at least for the activity types.

Would probably be nice to expose this field in the UI sometime.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you can control this options through UI but you can use hook_civicrm_summaryActions() to remove the options from the list.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: TY! I am not prepared to go this route but it's good to know I could. TY!

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_summaryActions/

Answer (score 1):

CSS based display:none; can be used to hide the ones you do not want, in combination with the other answers  (note; this is not a complete/secure solution)

For instance, if I want to hide the "Print Summary" action:

```
li.crm-contact-crm-contact-print {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could install the [Activity Type ACL](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl) extension and adjust what user roles can edit/view/delete a given activity type in the user permissions. However, this would not apply to administrator level users so you would need to use a different method as already mentioned by others for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Fast Action links extension from [Jon Goldberg](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/12/jon-g-megaphone-tech) will do what you want - see the repo [here](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.megaphonetech.fastactionlinks) and the documentation page [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/fastactionlinks/en/latest/)

Comment: No, unfortunately not - though I've considered adding that feature!  That extension lets you add new options next to the "View/Edit/Delete" links on contact/contribution search results.